# How to get rid of duplicate combinations after merging multiple dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas

I have merged a list of dataframes into one bigger dataframe using reduce and merge.

In the example, the common columns used to merge the dateframes are the Name, Number, and Country columns. But, for each set of duplicates, it generates all possible combinations. I would like as little rows as possible for each set of duplicates. Duplicates are classified by the Name column.

I have tried:

```
merged = reduce(lambda left, right: pd.merge(left, right, on = ['Name', 'Number', 'Country'], how = "outer"), list_of_dfs
```

Which results in:

| Name | Number | Country | Fruit | Sport | Street | School | Color | Grade |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jack | 23 | Canada | Banana | Basketball | Kiss | Middle | Blue | 91 |
| Jack | 23 | Canada | Banana | Basketball | Kiss | High | Blue | 91 |
| Jack | 23 | Canada | Banana | Basketball | Boss | Middle | Blue | 91 |
| Jack | 23 | Canada | Banana | Basketball | Boss | High | Blue | 91 |
| Jack | 23 | Canada | Banana | Soccer | Kiss | Middle | Blue | 91 |
| Jack | 23 | Canada | Banana | Soccer | Kiss | High | Blue | 91 |
| Jack | 23 | Canada | Banana | Soccer | Boss | Middle | Blue | 91 |
| Jack | 23 | Canada | Banana | Soccer | Boss | High | Blue | 91 |

This is just one example of a set of duplicates with all the combinations. I would like to have as little rows as possible. Some sets of duplicates have up to 16 combinations.

Here is an example of 6 dataframes being taken in:

| Name | Number | Country | Fruit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jack | 23 | Canada | Banana |

| Name | Number | Country | Sport |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jack | 23 | Canada | Basketball |
| Jack | 23 | Canada | Soccer |

| Name | Number | Country | Street |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jack | 23 | Canada | Kiss |
| Jack | 23 | Canada | Boss |

| Name | Number | Country | School |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jack | 23 | Canada | Middle |
| Jack | 23 | Canada | High |

| Name | Number | Country | Color |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jack | 23 | Canada | Blue |

| Name | Number | Country | Grade |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jack | 23 | Canada | 91 |

The desired output is:

| Name | Number | Country | Fruit | Sport | Street | School | Color | Grade |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jack | 23 | Canada | Banana | Basketball | Kiss | Middle | Blue | 91 |
| Jack | 23 | Canada | Banana | Soccer | Boss | High | Blue | 91 |

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and put there sample (small) input and expected output? (in text form)

Comment: There are no duplicates in your sample

Comment: @AndrejKesely I made the edits

Answer (score 0):

You need to [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html).

You can do it in the end (`merged.drop_duplicates()`), but the best would be to do it in the beginning, this will avoid creating the combinations of rows in the first place:

```
merged = reduce(lambda left, right: pd.merge(left, right, on = ['Name', 'Number', 'Country'], how = "outer"), [d.drop_duplicates() for d in list_of_dfs])
```

You can use a subset of columns if desired:

```
merged = reduce(lambda left, right: pd.merge(left, right, on = ['Name', 'Number', 'Country'], how = "outer"), [d.drop_duplicates(subset=['Name', 'Number', 'Country']) for d in list_of_dfs])
```

Answer (score 0):

With your example I think `pd.concat` is enough (just set the right indices):

```py
out = pd.concat(
    [df.set_index(["Name", "Number", "Country"]) for df in list_of_dfs], axis=1
).reset_index()
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
   Name  Number Country   Fruit       Sport Street  School Color  Grade
0  Jack      23  Canada  Banana  Basketball   Kiss  Middle  Blue     91
1  Jack      23  Canada  Banana      Soccer   Boss    High  Blue     91
```

---

EDIT: If the dataframes have different indices, you can try:

```py
indices = ["Name", "Number", "Country"]
list_of_dfs = [df.reset_index().set_index(["index", *indices]) for df in list_of_dfs]

out = pd.concat(list_of_dfs, axis=1).reset_index().drop(columns="index")
print(out)
```

Comment: I get the error, Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects.